set defaultValue on shadcn Combobox
i want to set defaultvalue my form that use combobox to select city for my edit page
this is my combobox code
    <Command>
      <CommandInput placeholder="Search kota..." />
      <CommandEmpty>No kota found.</CommandEmpty>
      <CommandList>
        {cities.map((city) => (
          <CommandItem
            key={city.id}
            value={city.name}
            onSelect={() => {
              setData((data) => ({
                ...data,
                city: city.id.toString(),
                subdistrict: "",
                village: "",
              }));
              fetchSubdistrict(city.id);
              setVillages([]);
              setValue(city.name);
              setOpen(false);
            }}
          >
            {`${city.type} ${city.name}`}
          </CommandItem>
        ))}
      </CommandList>
    </Command>


shadcn/combobox does not provide support of defaultValue property. but i assume that you keep selected city in state using useState hook. most likely it is defined something like this:
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

So, in order to mimic behavior you need, you could just supply initial value to useState hook:
const [value, setValue] = useState(cities[0]?.name);

